# {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", google cloud

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Got this error while deploying cloud functions with node version: Node.js 8 (Beta)

> Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "npm_install had stderr output:\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/typedarray-83fafd37/.travis.yml'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-c4f762ab/lib/_stream_transform.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-840f6280/lib/_stream_transform.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-c4f762ab/lib/_stream_writable.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-d7e024ba/lib/_stream_transform.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-840f6280/lib/_stream_writable.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/readable-stream-d7e024ba/lib/_stream_writable.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/protobufjs-e78f053b/dist/protobuf.min.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/jimp-a023a0b7/browser/examples/test.html'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/jimp-a023a0b7/browser/lib'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/jimp-a023a0b7/browser/lib'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/ajv-95df8818/dist/ajv.min.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/jimp-a023a0b7/browser/README.md'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@firebase/database-9dc4a163/dist/index.d.ts'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/@firebase/database-9dc4a163/dist/index.esm.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/moment-45f2522a/min/moment-with-locales.min.js'\nnpm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/node_modules/.staging/googleapis-329f5f2f/build/src/apis/bigquery/v2.js'\nnpm ERR! code E404\nnpm ERR! 404 Not Found: har-validator@5.1.2\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR! /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-01-10T13_28_58_185Z-debug.log\n\nerror: npm_install returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "C5E68EBB"}}

Comment: I am getting the same error. did you figure out this ? I have delete the package-lock.json file. but getting error with my local modules. are you using any local modules inside you function folder ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing "package-lock.json" file.

Comment: When using Python, `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` must also be excluded via `.gcloudignore`.

Comment: I dont have a package-lock.json to remove? @Jennings

Comment: what error did you get ? is that the same error i have put to display ? does that occured while deploying in google cloud function ?

Comment: This didn't work for me, but removing node_modules and running npm i, as mentioned in Jai Prestion's answer.

Comment: `find . -name "*lock.json"`

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE** (25/11/19)

As per @Jennings' answer, removing `package-lock.json` or `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is the quick temp fix. It seems the problem is related to Node 10: I can deploy just fine with Node 8, but when using 10 I need to remove the lock file. Of course Node 10 runtime is still in Beta, so...

---

This is a very stupid error with cryptographic logging.

Try any of the following:

- Using node 8 instead of node 10 (though recently fixed internally, I have found there are still issues with node 10)
- Check for possible corrupted or recently-installed dependencies, and remove
- Nuking `package-lock.json` and `node_modules` and running npm install

For me, it was the first option that got things in motion again. I also re-initialised firebase, reinstall firebase-tools and tried different node versions, though I don't think these steps made any difference.

Comment: @luis.parravicini please consider upvoting if this answer helped you

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Cloud functions, Check whether you have any errors in the JSON format which you have used in package.json file.

Answer (score 0):

When deploying Cloud Functions, I found that a single dependency problem in package.json can cause these large error blocks where it seems to be throwing errors for all dependencies.

In my case, I had a dependency version for "plaid" that was too high.  I had to roll back "plaid" to 4.0.0 - for some reason I thought the current version was higher and tried to use 6.0.0, which doesn't exist.  This caused a long list of errors from all modules.

The errors seemed to be coming from all modules, so I thought I had a Node.js version problem (which I had also recently updated), or a problem with my node_modules path.  But when I started taking out dependencies one at a time, it was just a single dependency that was causing all the errors.

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.3.0",
    "mysql": "^2.0.0",
    "plaid":"^4.0.0"
}
```